# Keystone effect in high-budget movies

Tags: cinematography, 3d, avatar

Avatar 3D has gigantic [keystone effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystone_effect) throughout the whole film. See feature points for one frame:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vJXhZQT.jpg]

Obviously, it happened, because converged cameras were used. But none of modern movies that I watched had such distortion.

The question is, what are other high-budget 3D movies with keystone effect? Do they exist at all, or Avatar is unique on that matter?

Comment: The answer will be a list of movies, I don't know if this is on topic here...

Comment: Flagged as *Too broad*